# Macros work individually, error when run together

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code in a Class Module:

```vb
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents MyQuery As QueryTable

Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)

MsgBox ("data is refreshed")
MsgBox ("about to clear key ranks")
Call Module2.ClearKeyRanks

MsgBox ("about to vlookup")
Call Module2.VL

MsgBox ("about to replace 0's")

Call Module2.replace_zeros

MsgBox ("about to sort keys")
Call Module2.SortKey
MsgBox ("about to refresh pvt")
Call Module2.refreshDisplayPivot
MsgBox ("querie initialized")
Call InitializeQueries
End Sub

Private Sub MyQuery_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)

Call Module1.InitializeQueries

MsgBox ("about to sort keys")
Call Module2.SortKey

MsgBox ("about to clear mem")
Call Module2.ClearMem

MsgBox ("about to memranks")
Call Module2.memRanks
MsgBox ("about to refresh")
End Sub
```

When I run each one of these macros individually in the workbook, it works.
When I try to do it by hitting the "Refresh All" option in the workbook, it goes through the steps and throws

> "Run-Time Error 50290: Application-Defined or object-Defined Error"

for the Module2.ClearKeyRanks step.

That code is:

```vb
Sub ClearKeyRanks()
    
Dim key As Object ' Excel Worksheet
Set key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Key")
    
key.Range("B2:B10000").ClearContents
```

I tried `Dim key As Worksheets` and it throws the same error.

From what I understand, the error is in `key.Range("B2:B10000").ClearContents`.

Comment: `Dim key as Worksheet` (not "Worksheets")`. Or was that a typo?

Comment: It def looks like youre trying to clear the range on an object of worksheets. Try not making it plural

Comment: Hey @BruceWayne. I tried it as Dim key As Worksheet also and it still throws me the exact same error.

Comment: @DougCoats do you mean try doing key.range("B2:B10000").clearcontent? Because that throws me a "Run-Time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method."

Comment: Quick test - comment out your `Set key...` line, and try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Key").Range("B2:B10000").ClearContents` and see if that works.  And of course, make sure you actually have a worksheet called `Key`.  If *that* throws an error, and you *do* have a "Key" worksheet, try just `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Key").Range("B2").Value` and see if it returns the value in `B2` in the Immediate Window (Press `CTRL+G` in the VB Editor).

Comment: @BruceWayne Pressing CTRL+G in the VB Editor after adding your debug code didn't return anything in the immediate window. But I do have a Worksheet in the workbook named "Key".

Comment: 1. press CTRL+G to get the immediate window (skip this if you already see it); 2. edit your code according to @batman and run it; 3. check output on immediate window

Comment: Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Key").Range("B2").Value returned a "1" in the immediate window, which is the value found in B2 in the Key worksheet.

Comment: add DoEvents before the call to allow the workbook to process any changes.

Comment: @Sorceri Should I add DoEvents before every Call?

Comment: @VBANoob Did it clear the error you were receiving?

Comment: @Sorceri So I did DoEvents before Call Module2.ClearKeyRanks(), but it still throws me the same 50290 Application-Defined or Objected-Defined error. And the error is still traced back to key.Range("B2:B10000").ClearContents

Comment: Could be event related, maybe try: Application.EnableEvents = False
key.Range("B2:B10000").ClearContents
Application.EnableEvents = True     --  Also, if you do a on error resume next is the output what is expected?

Comment: @Sorceri Should I be trying the application code in the Module with ClearKeyRanks or within the class module before/after Call Module2.ClearKeyRanks?

Comment: @VBANoob I would add it in the module

Comment: @Sorceri 

    Sub ClearKeyRanks()
    Dim key As Worksheet


    Set key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Key")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    key.Range("B2:B10000").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub

This gives me a Run-Time Error 50290: Method 'EnableEvents' of object'_Application' failed.

Answer (score 0):

I Just noticed that you do not declare a variable for Module2.  I assume Module2 is the name of the class?....

```
Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)

MsgBox ("data is refreshed")
MsgBox ("about to clear key ranks")

'declare a variable for the class
Dim myModule2 As Module2
'Initialize the variable
Set myModule2 = New Module2
'call the objects methods
Call myModule2.ClearKeyRanks

MsgBox ("about to vlookup")
Call myModule2.VL

MsgBox ("about to replace 0's")

Call myModule2.replace_zeros

MsgBox ("about to sort keys")
Call myModule2.SortKey
MsgBox ("about to refresh pvt")
Call myModule2.refreshDisplayPivot
MsgBox ("querie initialized")
Call InitializeQueries
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the macro was formatting the worksheets.
I solved deleting the line:

```
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

Then the macro run exactly as I wanted to.